# Copy next search criteria to Sheet1 B2

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I though this was a straight forward solution, but I am having problems working it out. I am searching the web via google. In sheet2 Column A I have a list of items i would like to search. I am trying to copy each item one at a time to sheet1 B2 so they can be searched.

Every time an item is searched it places the word "Done" in Sheet2 column B, I was trying to set the code to search Sheet2 column B, when it reaches a BLANK cell in column B, it copies the value of the cell A in Sheet2. It then pastes this value into Sheet1 B2 and the code goes back to the start and searches google for the new search criteria.

**My problem is**

I can not get it to copy the cell data from sheet2 A to sheet1 B2. Can some point me in the right direction.

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
      Set wb = ThisWorkbook
      Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    'Select cell B2, *first line of data*.
      ws.Range("B2").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        DoEvents
        ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B2")
        DoEvents
    
  
    If Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Stop" Then
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
        Set nextPageElement = Nothing
        Set div = Nothing
        Set link = Nothing

        MsgBox "Process Terminated"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    GoTo StartCode:
Loop
```

As always thanks in advance

I' Not super hot in writing code, but here its is as requested

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Start"

If Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Start" Then

Dim ie As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim nextPageElement As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim i As Long
StartCode: ' RESTART THE CODE FROM HERE


' ***** Currently this takes seach Criteria from Sheet1 Cell B1 and places it into google *****
url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").Value, " ", "+")

' ***** Gets internet explorer read, which is set to False so does NOT SHOW ******
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
.Visible = False
.navigate url
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With

Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
    DoEvents
'***** Searches for URLs and places the results into Sheet1 ROW 2 Column A *****
With Sheets("Sheet1")
pageNumber = 1
i = 3
Do
For Each div In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
            If div.getAttribute("class") = "g" Then 'r
            Set link = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
            DoEvents
End If
Next div

'''#####################  PAGE NAVIGATION GODE ############################
    DoEvents
'****** Searches Number of Pages entered in Sheet Cell C1, E.G 5pages *******
If pageNumber >= Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value, " ", "+") Then Exit Do
 
On Error Resume Next
Set nextPageElement = HTMLdoc.getElementById("pnnext")
If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
 
 On Error Resume Next


'****** Scrolls Down the Browser to mimic human behaviour *****
        ie.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999
'***** 1st Random delay in seconds from Max number entered in "Sheet1" Cell D1 *****
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value))
'***** clicks on google next page ******
        nextPageElement.Click
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop
'***** 2nr Random delay from Max number entered in "Sheet1" Cell E1 *****
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, Application.RandBetween(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value))
        Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    Loop
End With

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value = "Done" 'Add word "Done" to sheet2 column B

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    'Select cell B2, *first line of data*.
      ws.Range("B2").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        DoEvents
        ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("B2")
        DoEvents
    
  
    If Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Stop" Then
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
        Set nextPageElement = Nothing
        Set div = Nothing
        Set link = Nothing

        MsgBox "Process Terminated"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    GoTo StartCode: 'Go Back To Start
Loop
    
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
        Set nextPageElement = Nothing
        Set div = Nothing
        Set link = Nothing
        MsgBox "All Done"

End If
End Sub
```

'''##############    added today Tue - 9th - 2021 ###############

I have a list of search criteria in sheet2 column A, which I would like to be copied one at a time to sheet1 cell b2 so that search item can be searched on google, if it has "Done" in column B then it ignore that criteria as it has been searched

**Sheet2 -**  Search Criteria
[image: Search Criteria]

**Sheet1 -**  Search results -  Cell B2 is in RED this is the item beigh searched

[image: Search RESULTS]

Comment: Hi -can you share all the code? some observations

1. Where is `StartCode`? If it exists then your loop will only run once because this will break it out the first time it gets there

2. `ws.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1))` only needs to be `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` I think

3. I dont theink the `DoEvents` make any difference here

Comment: I read it as Copy and then the destination as the sheet I want in to paste into `sheet1 B2` What you are saying makes more scene now that i look at it, i need to give it a destination to paste into which is sheet1 b2